# Infinitely many zeros for solutions of Sturm-Liouville problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Task: Suppose that $q(x)>0$ and $q(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$. Then every nontrivial solution of $y''+q(x)y=0$ has infinitely many zeroes in $(0,\infty)$?

I have two results

1. ) If $q(x) \leq 0$ and $q(x)$ is continuous on $(x_1,x_2)$ then every nontrivial solution of $y''+q(x)y=0$ has at most one zeroes in $(x_1,x_2)$?
2. ) Sturm-comparision result

how can i use these two thm to prove the above problem?

Comment: Please find a shorter title for your question. Do not put the full question into the title. Use mathjax/LaTeX markup for formulas. I did most of that, please check if that is correct and make changes to suit your purposes.

Comment: @LutzL i don't now how to use latex/mathjax. Your changes are correct.

Answer (score 2):

The angle around zero of the curve $(y'(t),wy(t))$ (for some w>0) follows the differential equation
$$
φ'=\frac{d}{dt}\arctan(\frac{wy}{y'})=\frac{wy'^2-wyy''}{y'^2}·\frac1{1+\frac{(wy)^2}{y'^2}}
\\
=\frac{w(y'^2+qy^2)}{y'^2+w^2y^2}=w+\frac{w(q-w^2)y^2}{y'^2+w^2y^2}
$$
so that as long as $q(t)\ge w^2$ the phase trajectory has angular velocity greater $w$ and thus at least one zero crossing for $y$ in every segment of length $\frac\pi{w}$.

---

See also the [Sturm-Picone comparison theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem).

Comment: sir I think $q(x)>0$ only is not sufficient for infinite many solutions?

Comment: $\int_1^\infty q(x)=\infty $ is also required.

Comment: @neelkanth : What the calculation shows is that $\frac{\sqrt{q(t)}}\pi$ is about the local density of zero-crossings. So to get infinite zero crossings, you even need $\int_0^\infty\sqrt{q(t)}dt=\infty$.

Comment: If function $q(x)$ attained it minimum value say $k$ then by comparing       with $ y’’+ky$ by comparison theorem we can say that solution has infinite number of zeros . Now what if $q(x)$ does not attained its infimum value ? Please if possible I want proof in simple calculus . Proof given by you is not digested by me . Thanks .