# Non-Trivial solution if differential equation $y’’+q(x)y=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Exercise:** If  $q(x)>0$ and continuous function for $x>0$ then prove that every non-trivial solution of the differential equation $$y’’+q(x)y=0$$ has infinite positive  zeros .

Exercise $15$, Book - ordinary differential equation by Tyn Myint-U [image]

The same question also asked before [Infinitely many zeros for solutions of Sturm-Liouville problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053915/infinitely-many-zeros-for-solutions-of-sturm-liouville-problem/2054017?noredirect=1#comment8078746_205401) but I want some elementary solution because unable to understand this solution .

If $q$ attains it’s minimum values say $k$ then using comparison theorem [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm–Picone_comparison_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Picone_comparison_theorem) by comparing with $y’’+ky$ we can say that $y$ has infinite positive zeros . Now I am stuck if $q$ does not attained its minimum values and unable to compare with another differential equation. Please help  with elementary calculus way . Thanks .

Comment: I don't think you'll find an elementary solution because this isn't an elementary problem.

Comment: @K.defaoite But the case when q attains it minimum was easily solved .

Comment: If you think this problem is easy, why haven't you solved it yourself?

Comment: @K.defaoite it’s Tyn Myint-U book of ordinary differential equation book exercise and before excervise comparison theorem and basics concept are defined. I am thinking of using there theorem only . Chapter 3, exercise-14.

Comment: Stated in current form, the statement is false. Counter-example: $y(x) = \tanh(x)$ and $q(x) = \frac{2}{\cosh^2(x)}$.

Comment: @achillehui in some books the problem has extra condition as in Simmon differential equation book extra condition is $\int_1^\infty q(x)dx=\infty $

Comment: @neelkanth if the book has that condition, you need to add that to your question.

Comment: @achillehui then I have solution. I thought that it will because nice result if I find solution without this extra condition.

Comment: @achillehui can i say that $tanh(x) $ is not solution on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: @achillehui the differential equation $y’’+\frac{k}{x^2}y=0,0< k\leq \frac{1}{4}$ also work as a counter.